# Alternative to Paths in Java 6?

Tags: java, path, java-6

I want to retrieve the absolute path to the current directory in Java 6, but cannot use `Paths`.

```
String currentDirectory = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
```

What is the alternative?

Comment: A better idea is to switch to Java 8.  The past public release of Java 6 was made in 2013-04-16.  There have been a number of non-public releases since then with many security fixes.  **However** you can only get them if your organization has signed up with Oracle Inc for a Java support contract.

Comment: (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_6_updates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()

> Returns the absolute abstract pathname denoting the same file or directory as this abstract pathname
>
> Since: 1.2

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
new File(".").getPath();
new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File f = new File("");
String currentDirectory = f.getAbsolutePath();
```